# block of code that won't work. fopen function and %d

Tags: c

I am
trying to open multiple files with the 'j+1' counter and the '%d'
but won't work.
here is the piece of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <alloc.h>

FILE *string;
int j=0;

int main(void)
{   
    for (j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        string = fopen(("C:\\playlist%d.txt",j+1),"w+t");
        fclose(string);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an array to create the file name using `sprintf` and use the array in the call to `fopen`.

```
int main(void)
{   
   char filename[100]; // Make the array large enough
   for (j=0;j<10;j++)
   {
      sprintf(filename,"C:\\playlist%d.txt",j+1);
      string = fopen(filename,"w+t");
      fclose(string);
   }
   return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** This question originally had the **C++** tag.

---

> ```
> FILE* string;
> ...
> string = fopen(("C:\\playlist%d.txt",j+1),"w+t");
> ```

It seems you wanted to build a filename string with an integer value embedded inside.

(BTW: The choice of "string" as the name of the `FILE*` variable is not very helpful, I'd suggest using something more meaningful...)

Since this question is tagged with `[c++]`, you may want to use a convenient string class for that, with its overloaded operators, and the **`std::to_string()`** helper function to convert an integer to a `std::string`, e.g.

```
std::string fileName = "C:\\playlist";
fileName += std::to_string(j+1);
filename += ".txt";

FILE* file = fopen(filename.c_str(), /* other params */);
```

**PS** In addition to C's `FILE*`, in C++ there are specific **file stream classes** available for file management, like `std::fstream` and related ones.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The question was originally tagged with C++

As this is tagged as C++ you can do this with `std::string` and `std::fstream`

```
int main()
{
    std::string filename = "C:\\playlist";
    std::fstream file;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        file.open(filename + to_string(i) + ".txt");
        // do stuff
        file.close();
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```